Azure Devops pass pipeline parameter between stages
How can I pass the parameter from stageA to stageB?
The parameter output is an output from bicep file, called by a job.
I would like to use this output on the next stage.
enter image description here
Thx,
Istvan
I tried several format in StageB without success.

You can follow the steps below to get the value of output in Bicep and pass it between stages in pipeline:

Use the 'az deployment group show' command to get the value of output and pass it to a variable. See "Outputs in Bicep".
$itmValue = (az deployment group show - g <resource-group-name> -n <deployment-name> --query properties.outputs.itm.value)


Use the logging command "SetVariable" to set the variable as an output variable of the pipeline.
Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=itm;isoutput=true]$itmValue"


Then, you can pass the pipeline output variable between stages within the same pipeline run. See "Use output variables from tasks".


Below is a sample as reference.
variables:
  serviceconnection: xxxx
  resourcegroupname: xxxx
  RunNumber: xxxx

stages:
. . .

- stage: AVDImageTemplateCreator
  dependsOn: AVDImageDefinitionCreator
  jobs:
  - job: AVDinfrastucture
    displayName: 'Create Image Template'
    steps:
    - task: AzureCLI@2
      name: CreateImageTemplates
      displayName: 'Create Image Template'
      inputs:
        azureSubscription: $(serviceconnection)
        scriptType: pscore
        scriptLocation: inlineScript
        inlineScript: |
          az deployment group create `
            -g $(resourcegroupname) `
            -f solutions/avd/avd-cit-imagedep-d.bicep `
            -p parameters/avd/parameters.json `
            -n create_image-$(RunNumber)
          
          $itmValue = (az deployment group show -g $(resourcegroupname) -n create_image-$(RunNumber) --query properties.outputs.itm.value)
          Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=itm;isoutput=true]$itmValue"

- stage: ImageBuilderRun
  dependsOn: AVDImageTemplateCreator
  # Map the output variable as a stage-level variable for use.
  variables:
    imageTemplateName: $[ stageDependencies.AVDImageTemplateCreator.AVDinfrastucture.outputs['CreateImageTemplates.itm'] ]
  jobs:
  - job: ImageBuilderRun
    displayName: 'Run Azure Image Builder Image Build'
    steps:
    - pwsh: Write-Host "imageTemplateName = $(imageTemplateName)"
      displayName: 'Show value of imageTemplateName'
    # Steps to run the Azure Image Builder


